# cefsharp EvaluateScriptAsync does not return result count zero

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I want to use the cefSharp deploy on my winform project, but when I use the EvaluateScriptAsync it does not return any results, any ideas? I refer in [here](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1062)  and [here](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#2-how-do-you-call-a-javascript-method-that-return-a-result)   they have not solved my problem.

Here's my code：

```
private void browser_OnLoadEnd(object sender, CefSharp.FrameLoadEndEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Browser.MainFrame.Url.Contains("Passengers/Update"))
        {
            DriverMouse driver = new DriverMouse();
            object Result = null;
            var jsResult = @"(function () {return 'hello!';})();";
            try
            {
                e.Browser.MainFrame.EvaluateScriptAsync(jsResult).ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    if (!t.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        var response = t.Result;
                        Result = response.Success ? (response.Result ?? "null") : response.Message;
                    }

                }, TaskScheduler.Default);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error:{ex.Message}");
            }


            var x = _Random.Next(20, 500);
            var y = _Random.Next(50, 600);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            driver.DragTo(x, x, y, y);
            ChromiumBrowser.GetBrowser().MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(JsFile);
        }
    }
```

It's loading will be after the FrameLoadEnd Event.

[image]

Comment: Open devtools, manually execute your script, make sure it works. Try something simpler like 1 + 1. Your code is out of context so it's really hard to say what's going on.

Comment: yes,I have already tried to using @"(function () {return 'hello!';})();"; it still doesn't get the result.

Comment: Try literally 1 + 1

Comment: If your page has multiple frames then your code will be unreliable. Use e.Frame.IsMain to check and execute directly against e.Frame.

Comment: Aha,Let me try and Thanks your answer. amaitland.